# General question about curl in php

Tags: php, curl, vbulletin

It's simple question, can curl make posts on vBulletin forum? In PHP script so of course.

I didn't try that so just if anyone now or ever tried, to spare me some time I would appreciate a lot :D

If there is too much job, I'm not really sure if I should try to write that code

Answer (score 2):

> can curl make posts on vBulletin forum?

Sure it can. The worst part would be to catch tokens, login and other forms which requires to parse HTML

Answer (score 2):

While cURL can, you should more look at the [vBulletin API](http://members.vbulletin.com/api/). It contains a webservice to communicate with the vBulletin Board, which should be more suitable than the raw cURL method.